# Use of per IO data with IOCP based client

Tags: c++, oop, winsock2, iocp

I'm trying to create an IOCP TCP client and my code looks as follows:

**TCPClient.h:**

```
#pragma once

typedef struct 
{ 
    WSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped; 
    SOCKET Socket; 
    WSABUF wsaBuf; 
    char Buffer[1024];
    DWORD Flags;
    DWORD BytesSent;
    DWORD BytesToSend;
} PER_IO_DATA, * LPPER_IO_DATA; 

class TCPClient
{
public:
    TCPClient();
    ~TCPClient();

    bool Connect(const std::string strIpAddress, UINT32 uPort);
    bool Disconnect();
    bool SendCommand(const std::string strCommandName);
    bool ReceiveResponse();

private:
    static DWORD WINAPI ClientWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParameter);

private:
    SOCKET m_socket;
    PER_IO_DATA *m_pPerIoData;
};
```

**TCPClient.cpp:**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "TCPClient.h"

TCPClient::TCPClient() :
    m_pPerIoData(NULL)
{
}

TCPClient::~TCPClient()
{
}

bool TCPClient::Connect(const std::string strIpAddress, UINT32 uPort)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR)
        return false;

    HANDLE hCompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (!hCompletionPort)
        return false;

    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors; dwIndex++)
    {
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientWorkerThread, hCompletionPort, 0, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    m_socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();

        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(strIpAddress.c_str());
    server.sin_port = htons(uPort);

    CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)m_socket, hCompletionPort, 0, 0);

    if (WSAConnect(m_socket, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(server), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        WSACleanup();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool TCPClient::Disconnect()
{
    if (m_socket)
        closesocket(m_socket);

    WSACleanup();

    return true;
}

bool TCPClient::SendCommand(const std::string strCommandName)
{
    m_pPerIoData = new PER_IO_DATA;
    ZeroMemory(m_pPerIoData, sizeof(PER_IO_DATA));

    strcpy(m_pPerIoData->Buffer, strCommandName.c_str());

    m_pPerIoData->Overlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
    m_pPerIoData->Socket = m_socket;
    m_pPerIoData->wsaBuf.buf = m_pPerIoData->Buffer;
    m_pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len = strlen(m_pPerIoData->Buffer);
    m_pPerIoData->BytesToSend = m_pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len;

    DWORD dwNumSent;
    if (WSASend(m_socket, &(m_pPerIoData->wsaBuf), 1, &dwNumSent, 0, &(m_pPerIoData->Overlapped), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        {
            delete m_pPerIoData;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (TRUE)
        Sleep(1000);

    return true;
}

bool TCPClient::ReceiveResponse()
{
    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI TCPClient::ClientWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    HANDLE hCompletionPort = (HANDLE)lpParameter;
    DWORD NumBytesRecv = 0;
    ULONG CompletionKey;
    LPPER_IO_DATA PerIoData;

    while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &NumBytesRecv, &CompletionKey, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&PerIoData, INFINITE))
    {
        if (!PerIoData)
            continue;

        if (NumBytesRecv == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Server disconnected!\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // use PerIoData->Buffer as needed...
            std::cout << std::string(PerIoData->Buffer, NumBytesRecv);

            PerIoData->wsaBuf.len = sizeof(PerIoData->Buffer);
            PerIoData->Flags = 0;

            if (WSARecv(PerIoData->Socket, &(PerIoData->wsaBuf), 1, &NumBytesRecv, &(PerIoData->Flags), &(PerIoData->Overlapped), NULL) == 0)
                continue;

            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSA_IO_PENDING)
                continue;
        }

        closesocket(PerIoData->Socket);
        delete PerIoData;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TCPClient.h"

int main()
{
    TCPClient client;

    client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);

    client.SendCommand("Hello command\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My use of "m_pPerIoData" is clearly wrong because I'm newing every time I do SendCommand() and not deleting it properly.

- Q1. Where should I do m_pPerIoData = new PER_IO_DATA?
- Q2. Does it make sense to have a pointer to PER_IO_DATA as a member variable?

**Edit 2:**

I've done some renaming (Client -> Connection) to my existing code above because it was confusing me.

**Some background:**

- I'm creating a DLL that is used to control an ECR (Electronic Cash Register) device connected via LAN (or serial port).
- The DLL provides an easy-to-use interfaces such as Connect(), Disconnect() and also some ECR specific commands including Logon(), Logoff(), ReadCard() etc.
- (Probably overkill for my application but...) I'd like to make use of IOCP in my DLL to send/receive data to/from ECR asynchronously.

My top level class looks something like this:

```
#pragma once

#include "Connection.h"
#include "Uncopyable.h"
#include "ConnectionFactory.h"
#include "CommandName.h"

class Ecr : private Uncopyable
{
public:
    Ecr(const std::string& rstrConnectionInfo)
        : m_spConnection(ConnectionFactory::CreateConnection(rstrConnectionInfo))
    {
        //Initialise();
    }

    ~Ecr()
    {
        //Shutdown();
    }

    bool Initialise()
    {
        if (!m_spConnection)
            return false;

        m_spConnection->Initialise();

        return true;
    }

    bool Shutdown()
    {
        if (!m_spConnection)
            return false;

        m_spConnection->Shutdown();

        return true;
    }

    bool Connect()
    {
        if (!m_spConnection)
            return false;

        if (!m_spConnection->Connect())
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool Disconnect()
    {
        m_spConnection->Disconnect();

        return true;
    }

    bool Logon(const std::vector<BYTE>& rvecCommandOptions)
    {
        m_spConnection->SendCommand(CommandName::Logon(), rvecCommandOptions);

        return true;
    }

    bool Logoff()
    {
        m_spConnection->SendCommand(CommandName::Logoff());

        return true;
    }

    // ... more commands follow.

private:
    ConnectionPtr m_spConnection;
};
```

And I've got TcpConnection class which is created by the ECR class and does all the hard work.  Both Ecr and Connection classes are uncopyable.

**Connection.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "Uncopyable.h"

class CommandName;

class Connection : private Uncopyable
{
public:
    Connection(const std::string& rstrConnectionInfo);
    virtual ~Connection();

    virtual bool Initialise() = 0;
    virtual bool Shutdown() = 0;
    virtual bool Connect() = 0;
    virtual bool Disconnect() = 0;
    virtual bool SendCommand(const CommandName& rCommandName, const std::vector<BYTE>& rvecCommandOptions) = 0;
    virtual bool ReceiveResponse() = 0;

    bool SendCommand(const CommandName& rCommandName);

private:
    std::string m_strConnectionInfo;
};

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Connection> ConnectionPtr;
```

**TcpConnection.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "connection.h"

class TcpConnection : public Connection
{
public:
    TcpConnection(const std::string& rstrConnectionInfo);
    ~TcpConnection();

    // Connection
    bool Initialise();
    bool Shutdown();
    bool Connect();
    bool Disconnect();
    bool SendCommand(const CommandName& rCommandName, const std::vector<BYTE>& rvecCommandOptions);
    bool ReceiveResponse();

    static DWORD WINAPI WorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam);

private:
    SOCKET m_socket;
    HANDLE m_hIocp;
};
```

**TcpConnection.cpp:**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "TcpConnection.h"
#include "CommandBuilderTcp.h"

TcpConnection::TcpConnection(const std::string& rstrConnectionInfo)
    : Connection(rstrConnectionInfo)
    , m_socket(INVALID_SOCKET)
    , m_hIocp(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    m_socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
}

TcpConnection::~TcpConnection()
{
}

bool TcpConnection::Initialise()
{
    // Set up threads for using IOCP.

    m_hIocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);

    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors; dwIndex++)
    {
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkerThread, m_hIocp, 0, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)m_socket, m_hIocp, 0, 0);

    return true;
}

bool TcpConnection::Shutdown()
{
    // Release threads.

    return true;
}

bool TcpConnection::Connect()
{
    if (m_socket)
        return true;

    // Hard-coding IP address and port number for now.
    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.9.80");
    server.sin_port = htons(22000);

    WSAConnect(m_socket, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(server), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return true;
}

bool TcpConnection::Disconnect()
{
    if (m_socket)
        closesocket(m_socket);

    WSACleanup();

    return true;
}

bool TcpConnection::SendCommand(const CommandName& rCommandName, const std::vector<BYTE>& rvecCommandOptions)
{
    // Build full command from rCommandName and rvecCommandOptions and send to server.
    return true;
}

bool TcpConnection::ReceiveResponse()
{
    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI TcpConnection::WorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // Call GetQueuedCompletionStatus in a loop
    return 0;
}
```

A host application then creates a DLL instance per ECR device:

```
Ecr ecr("ipaddress+port");

ecr.Initialise(); // Or do this in Ecr's ctor?

ecr.Connect();

BYTE arrCommandOptions[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x18, 0xA6, 0x00, 0x01, 0x49, 0x08, 0x26};
std::vector<BYTE> vecCommandOptions(arrCommandOptions, arrCommandOptions + sizeof(arrCommandOptions) / sizeof(arrCommandOptions[0]));
ecr.Logon(vecCommandOptions);

ecr.Logoff();

ecr.Disconnect();

ecr.Shutdown(); // Or do this in Ecr's dtor?

return 0;
```

I want all the IOCP related stuff at the TcpConnection level, not the Ecr level because I don't want Ecr to care how data transmission is done underneath.

Is my idea not going to work?

Comment: You're creating a thread for each CPU *for each client*?? That's very inefficient and inconvenient. If you really want a parallel server, create as many worker threads as you have CPUs (globally, *not* for each client), than have them process events of *any* client, via a *single* completion port. And if you don't need parallelism, use a single thread and your life will be *much* easier. Also, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response.  RE: "use a single thread and your life will be much easier."  I thought IOCP requires worker threads being created.  Isn't that the case?

Comment: IOCP does not require threading, but threading does help. You are just not using the threads effectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau threading *always* makes development harder, not easier. With only a single thread, you don't have to worry with problems like race conditions and deadlocks.

Comment: @jpen IOCP doesn't require worker threads in the literal sense. You're free to just have the one single (main) thread call GetQueuedCompletionStatus() in a loop. I suggest you do that for a start, and only upgrade to multiple threads if your server turns out to be too slow.

Comment: Sure, if you don't want the code to scale upwards. Using a loop in a single thread can handle a moderate number of connections, but sooner or later you will have to introduce more threads to handle higher connection counts.

Comment: Personally I think it's worth designing to support multiple threads easily and allowing the number to be tuned at runtime. Designing for a single thread and then having to "add another thread" is likely to result in some bad decisions in the initial design.

Comment: Hi guys.  Please see my edit above.  I'm really stuck and would appreciate any advice you could give.  Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way. You need to be careful to make sure you manage your thread lifetime's correctly when you're creating threads in a DLL so this will complicate things a little - I would suggest that the API that your DLL exposes supports initialise and shutdown functions which manage the threads, perhaps.

Comment: @Len Thanks for your suggestion.  RE: **I would suggest that the API that your DLL exposes supports initialise and shutdown functions which manage the threads**. Something like this (please see my edit in the code)?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Just make sure the DLL's threads end before the DLL is unloaded.

Comment: @Len As you can see from my code above, I'm doing "CloseHandle(hThread);" in TcpConnection::Initialise().  Is it better to save each handle created by CreateThread() as TcpConnection's member variable (e.g., std::vector<HANDLE>) and close them in TcpConnection::Shutdown()?  Basically I don't know what kind of things I need to do in TcpConnection::Shutdown() in order to make sure the DLL's threads end before the DLL gets unloaded.

Comment: you need to tell them to stop working and then wait for them to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you showed is based on the IOCP code I gave you in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998504/winsock2-how-to-use-iocp-on-client-side/11092944).  However, that code was designed to re-use a single `PER_IO_DATA` instance across multiple IOCP operations on the same socket, because you were only reading in the client and only writing in the server.  Now you are mixing both reading and writing in the client, so you need to adjust the worker thread to support both types of IOCP operations by merging all of the code I gave you earlier, at then add an additional flag in the `PER_IO_DATA` so a completed operation knows whether it was a read operation or a write operation.

As for your questions:

> Where should I do m_pPerIoData = new PER_IO_DATA?

It doesn't make much sense to use a class-wide `m_pPerIoData` member at all.  `SendCommand()` is creating a new PER_IO_DATA, which is fine, you would just need to `delete` it when a worker thread has detected that all of `PER_IO_DATA::Buffer` data has finished being sent or the socket has been closed.

> Does it make sense to have a pointer to PER_IO_DATA as a member variable?

Not for the write operations, no.  You could have a single class member for reading, though.  Unless `SendCommand()` creates a new `PER_IO_DATA` when it is ready to read a single response.  The worker thread would then need to `delete` it when the full response has been received or the socket has been closed.

Comment: How should I go about deleting a pointer to PER_IO_DATA?  To do that I suppose I should store the pointer address somewhere but I don't know where...

Comment: Also RE: **Not for the write operations, no. You could have a single class member for reading, though.**  My TcpConnection class does both WSASend() and WSARecv(), not just WSARecv() so I should remove "m_pPerIoData" from the class in any way, is that right?

Comment: Once you submit an IOCP operation, you cannot delete the pointer until the operation completes or is aborted first. The examples I gave you earlier show how to get the pointer from the IOCP handler and even how to delete the pointer from inside that handler.

Comment: Cheers.  I'm closing this thread (it's getting too long) but I'll probably bother you again in another thread ;)

Answer (score 3):

Per I/O data has to exist for the lifetime of the I/O operation in question. So you probably want to dynamically allocate it, and pool it for reuse when you're done. I use a reference counting system, but that's just because I can keep my per I/O data alive for longer than a single I/O operation. The lifetime of I/O specific data is as follows:

- allocate before you issue the I/O operation (obviously)
- release when the operation completes, either successfully or with an error.

It doesn't really make sense to have the per I/O as a data member as it's "owned" by the I/O operation... You might have a I/O data "allocator" which can allocate these objects and which take ownership of them once the I/O operation has completed (pooling them for reuse).

You might like to take a look at some IOCP code that does this (and deals with the threading side of things in a scalable manner), see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've downloaded your framework.  I'm also reading your articles on CodePrject.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Am I correct in saying so far you guys have presented two ways to handle PER_IO_DATA?  Yours is to keep a collection of per I/O data and reuse them.  Remy's suggestion is to delete per I/O data every time a worker thread has detected a completion of the I/O operation or the socket has been closed.