# Handling multiple users using WinSock

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/6811/winsock-multi-client-servers) that shows how to accept multiple connections without use of multi-threading.

The problem I run into is that the `accept()` function always return `SOCKET_ERROR`.

I want the server to accept multiple clients. I'd like if someone can point me to what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my server code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

//sockets
#define CLIENT_CON 10
#define CLIENT_DIS 20
#define BF_SZ 100
#define MAX_CONS 5

SOCKET sock, clien;
int PR_CONS = 0;

struct _client
{
    bool con; // Set true if a client is connected
    sockaddr_in addr; // Client info like ip address
    SOCKET cs; // Client socket
    fd_set set; // used to check if there is data in the socket
    int i; // any piece of additional info
};
_client client[10];

int accept(_client*);
int send(_client*, char*,int);
int recv(_client*, char*, int);
void Server_Status(int );
void char_message(char*);
void accept_clients();
void recv_client();

int main() {
    //int res;
    int i = 1;
    int port = 5150;
    SOCKET sock;
    WSADATA ws;
    printf("\t Echo Server (Multiple client support)\n");
    sockaddr_in ser;
    ser.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ser.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    ser.sin_port = htons(port);
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&ws);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    bind(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&ser, sizeof(ser));
    listen(sock,5);
    printf("listening \n");
    unsigned long b= 1;
    ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,&b);

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS; i++) {
        client[i].con = false;
    }

    while(true) {
        accept_clients();
        recv_client();
    }       
}

int accept(_client* x) {
     x->i = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
     x->cs = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&x->addr, &x->i);
     if(x->cs != INVALID_SOCKET ) {
         std::cout << x->cs << std::endl;
         x->con = true;
         FD_ZERO(&x->set);
         FD_SET(x->cs,&x->set);
         printf("accepted client");
         return true;
     }
     //printf("failed to accept client");
     return false;
 }

 int send(_client* x, char* buffer, int sz) {
    x->i = send(x->cs, buffer, sz, 0);
    if(x-> i == SOCKET_ERROR || x->i == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }

 int recv(_client *x, char* buffer, int sz) {
     if(FD_ISSET(x->cs,&x->set)) {
        x->i = recv(x->cs,buffer,sz, 0);
        if(x->i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

 void accept_clients() {
     for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS;  i++) {           
         if(!client[i].con) {
            if(accept(&client[i])) {
                Server_Status(CLIENT_CON);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Server_Status(int msg) {
    if(msg == CLIENT_CON) {
        PR_CONS++;
        printf("client has connected");
    }
    else if(msg == CLIENT_DIS) {
        PR_CONS--;
        printf("client has disconnected");
    }
    else {
        printf("we got unknown message");
    }
}

void chat_message(char* s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    for(int i = 0; i< MAX_CONS; i++) {
        if(client[i].con) {
            send(&client[i], s, len);
        }           
    }
}

void recv_client() {
    char buffer[BF_SZ];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS; i++) {
        if(client[i].con) {
            if(recv(&client[i],buffer, BF_SZ)) {
                if(buffer[0] == '/') {
                    if(strcmp(buffer, "/server_bang") == 0) {
                        chat_message("** Hi**");
                    }                   
                }
                else {
                    chat_message(buffer);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on `if(FD_ISSET(x->cs,&x->set))` what you're missing here is `select`, but since you are using Windows, Overlapped IO may be a better option for you.

Comment: @user4581301 I'd look into that later, for now i'm trying to learn based on this tutorial. should i put select inside  int accept(_client* x)?

Comment: You are not initializing some variables properly. You never check results returned by functions `socket`, `bind`, `listen` and so on. Also declaring functions with the same name as system functions is not a good idea.

Comment: I looked through the tutorial and I gotta say I didn't like it. I've been looking around to see if I can find a better one for you to follow.

Comment: The tutorial writer is either doing something really sneaky that I've never seen before or some of the code is missing. I cannot find `select`, `poll`, `epoll` or any of the other usual suspects on the blog page.

Comment: @VTT i did it on purpose, the few times I used socket I never run into error involving them so I want to short up code this time.

Comment: Here's [Beej's page on select-based servers](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/advanced.html#select). Should be better reading than what you've been fighting with. By the way, in C++ a leading underscore often means something. Because it's in the global namespace `_client` is a reserved identifier. More on that here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Here's a question on Overlapped IO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998504/winsock2-how-to-use-iocp-on-client-side Scroll on down to Remy's answer for a code sample and discussion in the comments.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks I'll look into what you linked.

Comment: You are following it very poorly. Not only have you introduced an error, you have also removed all the error handling. Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I run into is that the `accept()` function always return `SOCKET_ERROR`.

That is because you are passing it an invalid `SOCKET` handle (had you bothered to check with `WSAGetLastError()` after receiving `SOCKET_ERROR`, it likely would have returned `WSAENOTSOCK`).

The reason is because your `accept()` wrapper function is calling Winsock's `accept()` function with a **global `SOCKET` variable** named `sock`, but your `main()` function never initializes that variable!  It is instead initializing a **local `SOCKET` variable** that is also named `sock`.  You need to either:

- get rid of `main()`'s local `sock` variable so `main()` will then use the global `sock` variable.
- get rid of the global `sock` variable, and have `main()` pass its local `sock` variable as an input parameter to your `accept_clients()` function, which can then pass it as an input parameter to your `accept()` function.